# grails show wait page on form submit

Tags: forms, grails, asynchronous

I have a form that the user submits and returns a result, but it takes a couple of seconds to return the result. I know I can use grails formRemote http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formRemote.html to execute the call asynchronously and update a div on the page, but what I want to do is show another page entirely (with some wait graphics and other information).

Is there an easy way to do this in grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send data to server asynchroniously (ajax, formRemote), showing 'wait graphics' util you get a response. And redirect to result page right after getting response (and you should have to store state somewhere, and probably have unique url for result page)

Comment: Igor, thanks. I would like the wait page to be its own page though since I show other things on there (possibly advertisements for example).

Comment: I was thinking the controller would render the wait page by default and then I could use something like cometd or atmosphere to render the data when it is available, but I'm not sure if this is overkill and if there is a simpler way to do this.

Comment: At this case you should post data to this 'own page' anyway (and show wait graphics?)

Comment: Agreed. I would post it to the wait page, and then the wait page would be notified when the task is done and hide the wait graphic and display the results.

Comment: I thought that the problem is with actual uploading. If it's about processing, then I don't see any problem here, you can always show any page and redirect to any other page at any moment.

Comment: Not sure I follow exactly how though. Let's say I have controller FormHandler that is called from the form submission. It then redirects to a wait page. That wait page needs to somehow be notified when the process completes so it can then redirect to the results page, doesn't it? That's the part I'm getting hung up on.

Comment: Ok, got it. There is Athmosphere Plugin  http://grails.org/plugin/atmosphere and Pusher Plugin http://grails.org/plugin/pusher, and of course you can make ajax call on timer. Can't say anything about overill, maybe first options will be overkill if you have only few users, but seems that it's not a lot of work, so it's up to you