# grails post form to another page with async result

Tags: ajax, grails, atmosphere

I have a form in my app and I would like to allow users to submit the form and be redirected to another page which will update asynchronously as results are available. I'm wondering how to do this.

My first thought was to synchronously submit the form and immediately redirect to the results page which will initially be empty. Then use some version of Ajax push (such as atmosphere) to listen for results.

Is this the correct approach or are there easier ways to approach this problem?

I know this is similar to another question I asked( [grails show wait page on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076054/grails-show-wait-page-on-form-submit)) but expands on some of the comments to make a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed solution (do a normal form submit/redirect and then server-push the results) is about the best you can do, assuming you want real-time updates to the results.